# How to Convert Audio File in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

I want to **programmatically** convert audio WAV file to a compressed audio file (IMA4 or iLBC).

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TPAACAudioConverter](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter) and [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html)